# how to pass parameter to function of mysql through vb.net adapter which is created by query builder wizard

Tags: mysql, vb.net, mysql-function

I have this query:

```
 SELECT * FROM table_1 WHERE (`update_column` = (DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 10 DAY)))
```

It works normally, I want to change 10 day to parameter and pass value of it through adapter, I'm using query builder, with query in adapter:

> FillBy_sub_date

Which i want to be like:

```
 SELECT * FROM table_1 WHERE (`update_column` = (DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL @_days DAY)))
```

And i want to pass day value with the following method:

```
  Me.table_1Adapter.FillBy_sub_date(Me.dataset.table_1, 5)
```

5 is the number of day which i wont to pass to query

Problem: when i change number 10 to @_days mysql error showing

> Error in list of function arguments: '_days' not recognized.
>   Unable to parse query text.

[image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TbS-p2gTMv02mFUdfaFBmJeusG0UZWxY/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Remove backticks from `INTERVAL` keyword.

Comment: same error still appear  , the problem with parameter not with INTERVAL , because when set ( INTERVAL  10 day ) it work normally ,
Error in list of function arguments: 'dd' not recognized.
Unable to parse query text.
where dd is @dd that passing to query instead of 10 day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is more then one way ,
 first create procedure in your mysql database with parameter
let call it "return_after_some_days"
your query is correct so put it inside procedure

1. create procedure

   ```
   CREATE PROCEDURE return_after_some_day (in param1 INT)
   BEGIN
   SELECT * FROM `table` where `update_column` = (DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL param1 day  ));
   ```

   `end;`
2. then go to your builder wizard and add query to table adapter
3. select  use existing stored procedure
4. from list select your procedure name which is   (return_after_some_days)
5. select tabular date and set name of fill method
6. go inside your code and call your method name from data adapter like

> Me.table_1Adapter.name_of_method_that_call_procedure(Me.dataset.table_1,
>   5)

number 5 will be pass to proceuder